# Depend on build-in package

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I'm making a smart package that depends on `showdown`, which is a built-in Meteor package. How do I mark this dependency? After putting

```
packages: {
  'showdown': {}
}
```

in `smart.json` I got a "Package doesn't exist on Atmosphere" error.

Comment: why is that necessary? in case that package will ever *not* be part of the core meteor anymore?

Comment: This package is not among "standard" ones, so the app might not have it installed. I want to ensure that it's loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only put packages in the smart.json if they are packages from Atmosphere, or you want them to be pulled in from git in which case you can pass a git URL like so:

```
'my_git_package': {
    'git': '<git_url_here>'
}
```

What you need to do is add the dependency in your package.js file:

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.use(['showdown'], ['client', 'server']);
});
```